# react axios instance keep reloading

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new learning react. I have problem with axios instance.

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
    headers: {
        ContentType: "application/json",
    },
});
```

this is working fine with 127.0.0.1:8000. But it's keep reloading when I change baseURL into "http://192.168.10.1:8000".

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://192.168.10.45:8000/",
    headers: {
        ContentType: "application/json",
    },
});
```

Comment: is the `http://192.168.10.45:8000/` link returned with a 200 status code?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect [IPv4 Address/Local Network] you must add your firewal Inbound rule on your host computer.

Maybe this can help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4SJNFqYE7A

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).